# Contact delegate node is not giving the same position

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a contact delegate to check when a player hits a barrier. When this player hits the barrier, the position of the barrier is saved onto a variable to be used

```
var movement : Movement

var collision : Int = 0

init(_ movement : Movement){
    self.movement = movement
}


    // Body B is the collision giver
    // Body A is the contacted node

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    collision += 1

    let categories : (taker: UInt32, giver : UInt32) = (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask, contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask)

    if categories.giver == Category.Player && categories.taker == Category.Barrier {
        movement.setBack.isOn = true
        movement.setBack.barrierPosition = (contact.bodyB.node?.position)!
    }

    print("Barrier position x")
    print(contact.bodyB.node?.position.x)

    print("Collision number")
    print(collision)
}
```

However, the problem is I have noticed that contact.bodyB.node?.position gives me a different value, even though the barrier has not moved. Since the position is different every time, then it is throwing off all the other classes. How can I make sure I get the accurate value every time?

**EDIT**

Added some debug messages:

```
    print("Barrier position x")
    print(contact.bodyB.node?.position.x)

    print("Collision number")
    print(collision)
```

And they print out:

```
Barrier position x
Optional(156.24853515625)
Collision number
1
```

Then I collide again

```
Barrier position x
Optional(151.248504638672)
Collision number
2
```

Comment: What kind of position differential are you experiencing? Like give me an example of the position printed, and the position expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rearrange your code as following:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let collision = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
    switch collision {
    case Category.Player | Category.Barrier:
        if case contact.bodyA.node?.categoryBitMask = Category.Barrier {
            movement.setBack.isOn = true
            movement.setBack.barrierPosition = (contact.bodyA.node?.position)!
        } else {
            movement.setBack.isOn = true
            movement.setBack.barrierPosition = (contact.bodyB.node?.position)!
        }
    default:
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Another thing you could try is to make a protocol which has a function that returns the node's position, then make the barrier node to conform to the protocol, and then, inside the didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact), you can call the barrier's position function as following: movement.setBack.barrierPosition = (barrierNode as! ProtocolThatReturnsPosition).returnPosition().

Answer (score 0):

Umh, this should be correct because `didBegin` , and so your check inside, could be called multiple times. Imagine your player that hit the barrier, the barrier is touched in multiple points so that's normal.
If you need to save only the first position, you could handle a `Bool`

Something like:

```
var barrierTouched: Bool = false

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let categories : (taker: UInt32, giver : UInt32) = (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask, contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask)
    if categories.giver == Category.Player && categories.taker == Category.Barrier {
        if !barrierTouched {
            movement.setBack.isOn = true
            movement.setBack.barrierPosition = (contact.bodyB.node?.position)!
            barrierTouched = true
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: When I run a debug message it seems that the didBegin method is run only once per collision, so I don't think hay is the issue

Comment: So, are you absolute sure you have only one collision between player and barrier **everytime** happen a collision?

Comment: Yes, I added some debug messages, edited the post. Also tested your code and it is is the same problem

Comment: Well done, so my next question is : can you show how you have configured the barrier physics (physicsBody and all settings around..)